# Sorting/Collating/Separating a list of objects in Java

Tags: java

I have a list of objects and I need to put them in individual lists based on 3 different identifiers.

```
name: test
type: type1
subType: a

name: test
type: type1
subType: b

name: test
type: type1
subType: a

name: test
type: type1
subType: b

name: newTest
type: type1
subType: a

name: newTest
type: type1
subType: b
```

What I want is a list of lists of 3 items containing two items each. So the first list in the list would contain

```
name: test
type: type1
subType: a

name: test
type: type1
subType: b
```

Second Item would contain

```
name: test
type: type1
subType: a

name: test
type: type1
subType: b
```

And the third item in the list would contain

```
name: newTest
type: type1
subType: a

name: newTest
type: type1
subType: b
```

So in my algorithm, if I see the combination of test-type1-a already in the sub-list I'd create a new item in the main list to contain it but it can only contain the entities of name "test" and type "type1" but it can have the a and b.

I kind of started with

```
List<Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, Object>>>> map = new ArrayList<>();
```

But I'm stuck figuring out how to create a new list item and how to search the list of maps to see if I need to create a new map.

Figured one of the brilliant minds looking at this site might help me figure out a super easy solution using streams and groupings, etc...

Thanks!

Comment: How do you discern what to put in list one and two since they contain the same information?  What if you had three such identical triads of information?   How would you divide them between list one and list two?  What distinguishes the two lists and their contents?

Comment: @WJS If I see an 'a' already in a list, I create another list to add the second 'a'. Each list is a set 'a' and 'b'. Maybe a 'c' can show up. Also, as I traverse the list if I start with 'a', then the next one is 'a' followed by 'b', the 'b' should go into the second list as it's part of the second set.

Answer (score -1):

I would tackle the problem in two separate steps: first, group the types **a** and **b** into separate lists, and then "zip" the two lists into a single list.

```
List<Type1[]> doTheThing(List<Type1> input) {
    Map<SubtypeType, Queue<Type1>> grouped = res.stream().collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(
            Type1::getSubtype,
            Collectors.toCollection<Queue<Type1>>(
                LinkedList<Type1>::new)
        )
    );
    Queue<Type1> groupA = grouped.get(SUBTYPE_A);
    Queue<Type1> groupB = grouped.get(SUBTYPE_B);
    
    List<Type1[]> zipped = new LinkedList<>();
    while(!groupA.isEmpty() || !groupB.isEmpty()) {
        zipped.add(new Type1[]{groupA.poll(), groupB.poll()});
    }
    
    return zipped;
}
```